# How to convert code below to regular java for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

see code below I come across in different problem, and I want to convert to regular forloop but didn't work. Original code doesn't compile, keeps saying missmatch between string and int

```
for (i = array = list.length, b = 0; b < i; ) {
  ...
  b++;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert from another language to Java for this for loop ?

Comment: Please add an actual problem statement to your question.  Currently, you are just broadly telling us that the code is not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add important information in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i = array = list.length` - you can't do this
array is [] and list.length is int.
so it should be like this

```
    private String printList (Student [] list){
        String s = "";
        byte b;

        for (Student stud:list
             ) {
            s+=" \n\t" + stud.toString();
        }
        return s;
    }
```

But class Student should have implemented correct method toString();